# Finding max occurrence of a column's value, after group-by on another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, max, aggregate

I have a pandas data-frame:

```
        id                city
 000.tushar@gmail.com   Bangalore
 00078r@gmail.com       Mumbai
0007ayan@gmail.com      Jamshedpur
0007ayan@gmail.com      Jamshedpur
000.tushar@gmail.com    Bangalore
  00078r@gmail.com      Mumbai
  00078r@gmail.com      Vijayawada
  00078r@gmail.com      Vijayawada
  00078r@gmail.com      Vijayawada
```

I want to find id-wise the maximum occurring city name. So that for a given id I can tell that - this is his favorite city:

```
         id             city
000.tushar@gmail.com   Bangalore
00078r@gmail.com       Vijayawada
0007ayan@gmail.com     Jamshedpur
```

Using groupby id and city gives:

```
         id                   city       count
0  000.tushar@gmail.com       Bangalore    2
1      00078r@gmail.com        Mumbai      2
2      00078r@gmail.com      Vijayawada    3
3    0007ayan@gmail.com      Jamshedpur    2
```

How to proceed further? I believe some group-by apply will do that but unaware of what exactly will do the trick. So please suggest.

If some id has same count for two or three cities I am ok with returning any of those cities.

Comment: Another option is `pd.crosstab(df['city'], df['id']).idxmax(axis=0)` although `crosstab` might generate a very large frame if you have many unique values for id and city.

Comment: for the dataframe i mentioned, this crosstab snippet gives me only 000.tushar@gmail.com    Vijayawada    record.  i think it is finding the max city count on overall id set.Not the id wise max city count.

Comment: The [pandas recommended](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7301) approach is `groupby('id').apply(your_custom_function)`, per my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try double `groupby` with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html). Output is list of tuples (because `MultiIndex`), so use `apply`:

```
df = df.groupby(['id','city']).size().groupby(level=0).idxmax()
                              .apply(lambda x: x[1]).reset_index(name='city')
```

Another solutions:

```
s = df.groupby(['id','city']).size()
df = s.loc[s.groupby(level=0).idxmax()].reset_index().drop(0,axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df = df.groupby(['id'])['city'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
                     id        city
0  000.tushar@gmail.com   Bangalore
1      00078r@gmail.com  Vijayawada
2    0007ayan@gmail.com  Jamshedpur
```

Answer (score 5):

The [recommended](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7301) approach is `groupby('id').apply(your_custom_function)`, where your_custom_function aggregates by 'city' and returns the max value (or as you mentioned, multiple max values). We don't even have to use `.agg('city')`

```
import pandas as pd

def get_top_city(g):
    return g['city'].value_counts().idxmax()    

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
         [('000.tushar@gmail.com', 'Bangalore'), ('00078r@gmail.com',     'Mumbai'),
         ('0007ayan@gmail.com',   'Jamshedpur'),('0007ayan@gmail.com',   'Jamshedpur'),
         ('000.tushar@gmail.com', 'Bangalore'), ('00078r@gmail.com',     'Mumbai'),
         ('00078r@gmail.com',     'Vijayawada'),('00078r@gmail.com',     'Vijayawada'),
         ('00078r@gmail.com',     'Vijayawada')],
         columns=['id','city'],
         index=None
     )

topdf = df.groupby('id').apply(get_top_city)

id
000.tushar@gmail.com     Bangalore
00078r@gmail.com        Vijayawada
0007ayan@gmail.com      Jamshedpur

# or topdf.items()/iteritems() if you want as list of (id,city) tuples

[('000.tushar@gmail.com', 'Bangalore'), ('00078r@gmail.com', 'Vijayawada'), ('0007ayan@gmail.com', 'Jamshedpur')]
```