# how to group a column in table where we need get maximum occurred value in second column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

In Pandas I have a table

```
name sec
emp1 a       
emp1 a       
emp1 b       
emp2 a          
emp2 b       
emp2 c       
emp2 c
```

i want to extract each name with max count of sec like

```
  name sec
  emp1  a
  emp2  c
```

in pandas in know we can use groupBy but do not know how to get this format.

```
df.groupby(['name','sec']).size()
```

this will give

```
name sec
emp1  a  2
      b  1
emp2  a  1
      b  1
      c  2
```

but I need  this way with maximum occurrence of sec

```
  name sec
  emp1  a
  emp2  c
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174624/finding-max-occurrence-of-a-columns-value-after-group-by-on-another-column . I was able to solve my issue by using above link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use groupby and agg together.

```py
>>> df.groupby(['name'], as_index = False)[['sec']].agg(pd.Series.mode) 
   name sec
0  emp1   a
1  emp2   c
```

Comment: HI @Jaemin Thank you for your answer. Could you explain what pd.Series.mode will do here.

Comment: @Ramu Sompalli  As you want the maximum occured value, which is the mode function, we can use mode function. As we can't just simply use mode function, I used agg and pd.Series.mode in the agg

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `.size()`,
you are looking for `.mode()`.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html

Comment: HI @J_H thank you for your answer. I am not able to understand how to use it. If you do not mind can you share an example.

Answer (score 0):

mode won't work for .groupby()

A big chain in pandas will work:

```
df.groupby(['name','sec']).size().reset_index().sort_values(by=0,ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset='name', keep='first').drop(columns=[0]).reset_index(drop=True)
```